# How to import libraries from Odoo Automated Action

Tags: automation, odoo, action

I'm trying to send a request to the server via an automated action in Odoo. i.e , lets suppose a Sales Order is created. I want to send some of its data to the server and process it elsewhere as well.

I created an automated action with the "Execute Python Code" option. When i try importing the requests library i get the error:

```
"forbidden opcode(s) in 'import requests\n\nprint("test")': IMPORT_NAME"
```

Is it possible to import libraries via Odoo automated actions ? If not what are alternatives or workarounds that can be made ?

Here's an image for more clarification :

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Denis Ledoux**:

> `import` is indeed prevented in automated/server actions.
>
> This is expected in Odoo for security concerns: Adding it would mean
> anyone having the Settings access to your Odoo database would be able
> to import any Python module, and therefore do about anything they want
> with your database and server filesystem.
>
> e.g. `import shutil shutil.rmtree('.')  # Deleting all folders and files of current directory`
>
> This is even more problematic when your Odoo server hosts multiple
> databases: Any administrator of any database would be able to do about
> anything in all other databases and filestores. It does not apply to
> Odoo.sh, as each server is isolated and only host one database at a
> time. But, this behavior is a restriction of the standard Odoo server,
> which can have multiple databases hosted by the server, and this is
> therefore important to mention this case.
>
> Why don't you just create a custom module that overrides the `create`
> and `write` method of the model you want monitored, to contact this
> REST API endpoint ?
>
> - It will be safer,
> - It will scale better as your business/customization grows. Indeed, you will use the versioning of Git and have a history of what is done
>   for which reason by who.
>
> If you still want to be able to use imports in automated actions,
> which is STRICTLY UNADVISED for the reason stated above, you can
> create a custom module overriding the `_SAFE_OPCODES` list to add the
> given opcode `IMPORT_NAME`.
> https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/d7cfa8c502f27bee5c2fccb35db47b08e3b3804b/odoo/tools/safe_eval.py#L95

Source: https://www.odoo.com/de_DE/forum/hilfe-1/how-to-use-import-module-in-automated-action-in-odoo-sh-11-0-136386